# Getting values of dynamically added elements

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I cannot get the value of my dynamically added elements with jquery.

`public IEnumerable<GroupDetail> GroupDetaile { get; set; }` returns as `null`!

What should I do to get the values?

**My Model:**

```
public class elementmodel
{
    public group MyGroup { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GroupDetail> MyGroupDetail { get; set; }
}
```

**My View:**

```
function new() {
    var items = '@foreach(SelectListItem item in (SelectList)ViewData["Ceasers"]){<option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>}'
    i = i + 1
    $("#mytable").append("<tr><td><div id='dive" + i + "'><select name='MyGroupDetail[" + i + "].cea_id'>" + items + "</select><input type='button' value='-' id='buttonminus" + i + "' class='bumblebutton' style='width:5%;' onclick='removeelem(" + i + ")' /></div></td></tr>");
}
```

I want to fill this with my dynamically added elements value field:

```
public IEnumerable<GroupDetail> MyGroupDetail { get; set; }
```

I tried to do it by using this method:

```
name='MyGroupDetail[" + i + "].cea_id'
```

but somehow I still get the null value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found it! My code up there works what i just needed is starting with `0`

```
 $('document').ready( function() {
    var items = '@foreach(SelectListItem item in (SelectList)ViewData["Ceasers"]){<option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>}'
    i = 0;
    $("#mytable").append("...<select name='MyGroupDetail[" + i + "].cea_id'>" + items + "</select>...");
 });
```

it's all cause of : `public IEnumerable<GroupDetail> MyGroupDetail { get; set; }`

`IEnumerable` items always starts with `0` so dynamic elements should start with `0` too for getting the values back.